# Creating a GWT iFrame like screen

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, gwt, iframe

I have been developing an app with Java + GAE (1.8.6) + GWT (2.5.1) and now, as per a requirement of my client, i need to create a screen layout divided in two parts (25%,75%), being in the left side the options, and in the other 75% of the screen, the result of the option clicked (like a screen set as an iFrame).

I have tried to use a DockLayoutPanel with west and center panel added to them, but i cant manage to load the contents of each link placed in the west panel on the center panel.

I have been Google'ing for a solution or some code to adapt it to my needs, but so far I havent had much success.

¿Could you please help me out?. I bought also GWT in Action by Manning ed. but havent found much about this matter there.

Meanwhile i will keep looking around / trying to find a solution on my own.

Thank you in advance,

Kind regards,

Comment: A horizontal panel would already fit the requirements. On the left you build your menu, and on the right you drop a panel which you use as new "rootpanel". There is no need for an iframe.

Can you post your code how you create the ui?

Comment: Besides your answer, which I see it is completely valid, I imagined i could use a HTMLLayoutContainer, in which i would write a table, containing another two tables. One in one side, having the size of the menu options displayed as a list, and in the other side, the contents of the widget displayed when a specific option was clicked.

Comment: I was going to answer my question with the solution i found but : " Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer 11/21/2013 5:16:04 PM. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.". So i will post the answer in 8 hours as i intended in the first place. Thank you for your answer and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i found was:

```
//define framedPanel for later use
private FramedPanel fupanel;

//Instantiate the widget i want to add when the option is clicked
final FileUp fileUp = new FileUp();

//Create the HtmlLayoutContainer in which add the widget later on

HtmlLayoutContainer conEnlaces = new HtmlLayoutContainer(getTablaEnlaces());

public Widget asWidget() {
    if (fupanel == null) {
        fupanel = new FramedPanel();
        fupanel.setHeadingText("Administración");
        (some other code here)

      VerticalLayoutContainer p = new VerticalLayoutContainer();      

      conEnlaces.setWidth(Window.getClientWidth());

      fupanel.add(p);

      p.add(conEnlaces);

      Hyperlink fileUph = new Hyperlink();
      fileUph.setText("- Importación de CSV");
      conEnlaces.add(fileUph, new HtmlData(".fileUph"));  

      filexh.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            conEnlaces.add(filex, new HtmlData(".resultado"));

        }
    });

        fupanel.add(conEnlaces);
    }
    return fupanel;
  }

private native String getTablaEnlaces() /*-{
  return [ '<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">',
      '<tr><td>',
      '<table border="0" width="75%">',
      '<tr><td class=fileUph></td></tr>',     
      '</table></td>',
      '<td><table border="0" style="margin-left: 25px;">',
      '<tr><td class=resultado></td></tr>',
      '</table>',
      '</td></tr></table>'
  ].join("");
}-*/;               

public void onModuleLoad() {
    RootPanel.get().add(asWidget());
  }
```

---

And like this my problem has been solved. I have shown you my code because i get angry at times when using stackoverflow forums, and people say to have reached a solution, but dont explain how.

Thank you for your response and time,